# Switching between "Tabs" (via bottom navigation) - flickering, any advice?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout

I am currently writing a Messenger app for my Guild, currently I got as far as, I can log in and switch between different tabs, that lists currently dummy message titles (like a whisper name).

My goal later is that once you click on one of the messages you can reply / read messages in WhatsApp style (tips welcome here as well).

But my current issue is that I use the "Bottom" navigation menu. I swap the tabs currently with new activies. But whenever I click a button the screen "flickers" like, it's restarting the whole app.

Is there some way to switch "fluid" the upper part of the app, while the menu always stays nicely at the bottom?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace GuildMaster
{
    [Activity(Label = "Whisper")]
    public class Whisper : Activity, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        private ListView whisperlist;
        private List<string> itemlist;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            BottomNavigationView navigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation);
            navigation.SetOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            whisperlist = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.whisper);
            itemlist = new List<string>();
            itemlist.Add("Tim");
            itemlist.Add("Tom");           
            ArrayAdapter<string> whisper = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, itemlist);
            whisperlist.Adapter = whisper;
            whisperlist.ItemClick += Listnames_ItemClick;
            // Create your application here
        }
        public void Listnames_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, e.Position.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.navigation_home:
                    StartActivity(typeof(Whisper));

                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.navigation_dashboard:
                    StartActivity(typeof(Guild));

                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.navigation_notifications:
                    StartActivity(typeof(Other));

                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try working with fragments instead of activities with the bottom navigation, working with an activity means u have to start a completely new screen with a new bottom navigation, if that is what you are doing then it is completely normal to "flicker" when doing so

as a solution, use an activity with an xml that holds a fragment view and a bottom navigation view, and when u switch from the bottom navigation in your activity, switch the fragments loaded within the fragment view.

this can be done with different methods, but i would suggest checking out the Navigation Component from Google, since it will also handle the backstack for you.